What are examples for the use of reduplication in conlangs?
I have the feeling that the potential of reduplication is underexplored by conlangers. There are lots of fancy possibilities for reduplication; the above cited Wikipedia article describes them in detail, but see also Is C₁VC₂-C₁- reduplication attested? on the Linguistics Stack Exchange site.
So I want to hear of examples of reduplication in conlangs, ranging from descendants of Latin retaining some reduplication or even making it productive again, to a posteriori language using reduplication for some interesting effect.

Here's an example, Kerno, a fictive Romance language located in Cornwall, inherits some reduplication in the perfect tense. It often adds an optional -s- to the replicated part of the verbs. Examples taken from the Annex of the grammar are:
doc (or doy), dar, dedai, doú
istam, ystar, stet(ai), ystú
currem, currer, coscorrai (or cocorrai), cursú
ferrim, ferer, tetulli, latú
spondu, isponder, spepondai, isponsú
mordu, morder, mosmordai (or memordai), morsú

